# Rails: can I use elasticsearch-model and active_model_serializers together?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, elasticsearch, active-model-serializers

I'm building a JSON API in Rails and I'd like to use Elasticsearch in order to speed up responses and allow for search.

I'm just done implementing the elasticsearch-rails Gem for my first model and I can query ES from the console successfully.

Now I'd like to make results available to API consumers, so for example a GET request to /articles/index.json?q="blah" would retrieve the matching articles from ES and render them according to JSON:API standards.

Is it possible to use the rails active_model_serializers gem to achieve this? I'm asking because there (in contrast with jbuilder) the JSON:API format is already taken care of.

**EDIT**: Here's where I stand at the moment:

In my model I have the following:

```
require 'elasticsearch/rails'
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
    validates :user_id, :active, :status, presence: true
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

    index_name Rails.application.class.parent_name.underscore
    document_type self.name.downcase

    settings index: { number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 1 } do 
        mapping dynamic: 'strict' do 
            indexes :id, type: :string
            indexes :user_id, type: :string
            indexes :active, type: :boolean
            indexes :status, type: :string
        end 
    end

    def as_indexed_json(options = nil)
      self.as_json({
        only: [:id, :user_id, :active, :status],
      })
    end

    def self.search(query) 
        __elasticsearch__.search( { 
            query: { 
                multi_match: { 
                    query: query, 
                    fields: ['id^5', 'user_id'] 
                } 
            }
        } )
    end
end
```

This correctly indexes the model in ES and makes it possible to search the ES index.
In my controller I have:

```
class ThingsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        things = Thing.search(params[:query]).results.map{|m| m._source}
        render json: things, each_serializer: ThingSerializer
    end
end
```

In the serializer, at the moment, is the following:

```
class ThingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :id, :user_id, :active, :status
end
```

This unfortunately brings up the following JSON in the view:

```
{"data":[{"id":"","type":"hashie-mashes","attributes":{"user-id":null,"active":null,"status":null}}]}
```

So the serializer is not correctly parsing the result, which is wrapped from the ES gem into this Hashie::Mash object.

Comment: You might as well provide little code so we will not shot in the dark. However what you like to achieve is achievable with jbuilder

Comment: I have no code atm, I'm asking if this is doable at all.. I have elasticsearch-rails implemented in a model and I want to render the JSON via  active_model_serializers. Jbuilder is obviously the alternative but, as stated in the question, I would then have to make the data JSON:API compliant on my own for every model

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work nicely and without the need to fetch records from the DB. Here's the complete solution for future googlers:

Serializer (probably better to create a dedicated one for search results):

```
class SearchableThingSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  type 'things' # This needs to be overridden, otherwise it will print "hashie-mashes"
  attributes :id # For some reason the mapping below doesn't work with :id

  [:user_id, :active, :status].map{|a| attribute(a) {object[:_source][a]}}

  def id
    object[:_source].id
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
def index
  things = Thing.search(params[:query])
  render json: things, each_serializer: SearchableThingSerializer
end
```

With this you can build a JSON API as described in this guide, with the additional benefit of serving data straight from Elasticsearch:

https://www.simplify.ba/articles/2016/06/18/creating-rails5-api-only-application-following-jsonapi-specification/